# Fail on foreign constraint key

Tags: mysql, sql, foreign-keys, foreign-key-relationship

I'm trying to create a foreign key between the field `review_id` in table `Reviews` and `id` in table `Sentences`. The structure of the tables is the following:

```
CREATE TABLE `Reviews` (
  `review_id` varchar(255) CHARACTER SET utf8 NOT NULL,
  `package_name` varchar(255) CHARACTER SET utf8 DEFAULT NULL,
  `review_content` text CHARACTER SET utf8,
  `review_date` date DEFAULT NULL,
  `star_rating` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `app_version_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`review_id`),
  KEY `app_version_id` (`app_version_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

CREATE TABLE `Sentences` (
  `id` varchar(255) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `review` text,
  `category` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `topic` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  KEY `rev-id` (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

I'm facing with the following error and I don't understand what the problem could be.

```
ALTER TABLE `Reviews` ADD CONSTRAINT `rev-to-sents` FOREIGN KEY (`review_id`) REFERENCES `Sentences` (`id`)
Foreign key constraint fails for table `msr test db`.`#sql-75_d`:
,
  CONSTRAINT `rev-to-sents` FOREIGN KEY (`review_id`) REFERENCES `Sentences` (`id`)
```

Trying to add in child table, in index PRIMARY tuple:
    DATA TUPLE: 8 fields;
     0: len 36; hex 37626532323335652d616663392d313165362d383935342d633462333031636466363237; asc 7be2235e-afc9-11e6-8954-c4b301cdf627;;
    ...

Comment: Unfortunately, MySQL hides the actual error message when it comes to foreign key definition errors. You need to run `SHOW ENGINE INNODB STATUS` and find it in the «LATEST FOREIGN KEY ERROR» section. Please note that [show engine queries](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/show-engine.html) require the [`PROCESS` privilege](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/privileges-provided.html#priv_process), which your regular MySQL user may not have—you can either assign the privilege or run the query as root.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem sounds like you are trying to add a foreign key with rows that don't match.  If so your first task is to find the non-matching rows and determine the scope of the problem In other words you have cases where `Reviewes.review_id` does not match any value in `Sentences.id`

You need to find and fix your data first.  This means:

```
SELECT review_id FROM Reviews
  LEFT JOIN Sentences ON review_id = Sentences.id
 WHERE Sentences.id IS NULL;
```

Since you have a `NOT NULL` constraint on `Sentences.id`, only when the join condition fails, will the id be null.

Comment: Yes you are totally right. The error was due to a "non-match", that was totally unexpected to me. I'll fix the data and then I'll try again!

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
ALTER TABLE Reviews
ADD CONSTRAINT rev-to-sents
ADD FOREIGN KEY (review_id)
REFERENCES Sentences (id)
```